# Is it possible to get x,y coordinates while scanning image using tesseract?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tesseract

I am scanning image using tesseract library. I am getting the output from library in form of string . Is it really possible to get x and y position  along with the text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **hocr** command-line option, as follows:

```
tesseract eurotext.tif out hocr
```

The output will be an `out.html` file containing the coordinates of each recognized word.

Comment: how can i get those in my iPhone project ?

Comment: Can you invoke the command from your program? You can also call TessBaseAPI.GetHOCRText().

Comment: The question is for iOS ... The answer is for what ??